# SPGridView clear filter is disabled when multiple column having filter

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, spgridview

I have successfully implemented multiple column filter in SPGridView but facing an issue on clear filter. Clear filter is showing disabled for all columns on which I applied filter. If I filter on one column at a time its working fine. I researched a lot but no luck. Is there any specific logic which needs to be applied or I am missing something.

I appreciate any inputs.

Comment: can you add the code which you are trying?

Comment: Hi Anuja, 
Sure. It's very lengthy code because used with a big project and having lots of functionality together. I will extract the required part and share with you here.